# Flash as3 to PHP file not inserting data into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3

I cannot find any syntax errors for the life of me so I don't understand why the data is not being inserted into my database. When I run the script in my browser with text instead of variables and no if statement I get a successful connection but It doesn't insert the data into mysql. Its driving me nuts! Thanks in advance.

PHP:

```
<?php

// Establish secure connection
$link = mysql_connect('myserver', 'myuser', 'mypass'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connected successfully'; 
mysql_select_db(events_60); 


if ($_POST['requester'] == "NewSale") {

     $FirstName = $_POST['First_Name'];
     $LastName = $_POST['Last_Name'];
     $Birthday = $_POST['UserBirthday'];
     $PhoneNumber = $_POST['PhoneNo'];
     $Email = $_POST['UserEmail'];

mysql_query($link, "INSERT INTO events_60 (LastName, FirstName, Birthday, Phone, email) 
        VALUES('$LastName', '$FirstName',' $Birthday', '$PhoneNumber', '$Email')")
        or die ("SYSTEM FAILURE");

echo 'System Updated';
} // close first if for post

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// close mysql connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Did your browser prints any one of these at least? SYSTEM FAILURE or System Updated?

Comment: Neither I only get Connected successfully

Comment: If you only get Connected successfully I'm pretty sure the problem is that `$_POST['requester'] == "NewSale"` is false. Because if that is the case everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all data is posting correctly to the webpage I think the error resides here:

```
mysql_select_db(events_60);
```

It should be:

```
 mysql_select_db('events_60', $link);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Comment: In addition to a successful connection I am now getting a "die" from the query

Answer (score 0):

First of all select_db query should be

> mysql_select_db('events_60',$link);

Then second problem is in mysql_query. It should be like this:

> mysql_query("INSERT INTO events_60 (LastName, FirstName, Birthday, Phone, email) 
>          VALUES('$LastName', '$FirstName',' $Birthday', '$PhoneNumber', '$Email')",$link)
>          or die ("SYSTEM FAILURE");

$link identifier should come after query.

Hope that fixes it. :)